# I'm having trouble adding redundant values to a nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I cannot figure out why when I try to build a nested dictionary here, values that are the same get skipped over. Can anyone point out where my mistake is?

Here is the code:

```
def order_weight(strng):
    strlist= strng.split(' ')
    weighted_dict={}
    for n in strlist:
        digtotal=0
        for digit in n:
            digtotal+= int(digit)
        weighted_dict[strlist.index(n)]= {digtotal:n}
    print(weighted_dict)

order_weight("9999 11 11 22")
```

Ideally, this would output `{0: {36: '9999'}, 1: {2: '11'}, 2: {2: '11'}, 3: {4: '22'}}`
instead, it is outputting  `{0: {36: '9999'}, 1: {2: '11'}, 3: {4: '22'}}`

The second 2:11 pair is not getting saved, even though it has a unique key

Comment: What do you think `strlist.index(n)` returns for `n` being `11`?

Comment: Tip: Instead of going back and scrounging through `strlist` for the index, why not just pass that in so there's no guessing? Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). This has the bonus of reducing this to linear complexity, instead of exponential.

Comment: `stylist.index` doesn't *remember* that it already returned an index for the first 11, and now should return the index for the second one. You should stop using `index

Comment: yes indeed! my real problem was a lack of understanding of how .index() works. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

When you use `strlist.index(n)`, you get the index of the first occurance of `n`. Since the first `11` is the same as the second `11`, this will make both indexes be `1`.

Use `enumerate` to keep track of the index

```py
def order_weight(strng):
    strlist = strng.split(' ')
    weighted_dict = {}
    for index, n in enumerate(strlist):
        digtotal = 0
        for digit in n:
            digtotal += int(digit)
        weighted_dict[index] = {digtotal:n}
    print(weighted_dict) # {0: {36: '9999'}, 1: {2: '11'}, 2: {2: '11'}, 3: {4: '22'}}

order_weight("9999 11 11 22")
```

Alternatively, it doesn't look like you need a `dict`ionary as the output, and a list makes more sense here. With a `list`, you can just `.append` to it

```py
def order_weight(strng):
    strlist = strng.split(' ')
    weighted_list = []
    for n in strlist:
        digtotal=0
        for digit in n:
            digtotal += int(digit)
        weighted_list.append({digtotal:n})
    print(weighted_list) # [{36: '9999'}, {2: '11'}, {2: '11'}, {4: '22'}]

order_weight("9999 11 11 22")
```